# change sub UIView background color

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, background-color

I'm trying to add subview in my `ViewController` using this method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    addCourse = [[UIView alloc]init];
    addCourse.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addCourse.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
    [addCourse.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

Where `addCourse` is my `subview` but the background color is still white. and I'm using `storyboard` and added the `subview` with it and linked the View with `viewcontroller` and I did write the IBOutlet and the property and synthesize  but still I couldn't find a way to change the background color.

How I can change it ?

Comment: how you have added addCourse into ViewController?

Comment: 1.You haven't set a frame 2. You haven't added the subview to the main view! Then how will you get it?

Comment: set the frame and add the subview to self.view.  addCourse.frame=CGRectMake(10.0,10.0,200.0,200.0); [self.view addSubview:addCourse];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already linked with the ViewController then you just need to remove the below line from your code

```
addCourse = [[UIView alloc]init];
```

Because, it create the new instance of your subView.

Comment: I deleted that line and everything was working fine , thank you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added `addCourse` to your view controller as as I can see. replace your `viewDidLoad` method with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    addCourse = [[UIView alloc]init];
    addCourse.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addCourse.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
    [addCourse.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    //ADDED THIS LINE
    self.view = addCourse;
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Do you mean [self.view addSubview:addCourse]; ??

Answer (score 0):

```
addCourse = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
addCourse.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[addCourse.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
[addCourse.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[self.view addSubview:addCourse];
```

Answer (score 0):

See I have updated your code (Just you need to Set View's Frame) and I got the Result

Please! Update your code this way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //custom view
    UIView *addCourse = [[UIView alloc]init];
    CGRect myViewframe = CGRectMake(10.0f, 90.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    addCourse.frame=myViewframe;
    addCourse.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addCourse.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
    [addCourse.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    
    [self.view addSubview:addCourse];
}
```

and Here is the result screen

[image]